# Criar laço e passar para argumentos de uma função?

Tags: python, funções, loop, for, while

Tenho o seguinte código em Python:

```
storage.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 30)
storage.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 140)
storage.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 90)
storage.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 55)
storage.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(4, 60)
storage.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(5, 40)
```

ele acessa cada coluna em um tableWidget(primeiro argumento) e define o tamanho da célula(segundo argumento).

Me falta conhecimento, mas creio que seja possível diminuir esse código com algum laço, tendo em mente que o primeiro argumento é sequencial (0,1,2,3,4,5).
Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

obrigado.

Comment: https://ideone.com/dIV9D7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer utilizando enumerate:

```py
tamanho_celula = [30, 140, 90, 55, 60, 40]

for col, tamanho in enumerate(tamanho_celula):
    storage.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(col, tamanho)
```

Na primeira linha você cria uma lista com os valores do tamanho da célula e dentro do for você itera.

Comment: O enumerate busca o índice junto?

Comment: ele adiciona um "contador" ao laço for, o enumerate aceita que você coloque como argumento opcional de qual número ele vai começar a contar.